# Can you spot the mistake?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Let $$I=\displaystyle\int\sin^2x \ dx$$then

$$I=\displaystyle\int(1-\cos^2x) \ dx=x+C-\displaystyle\int \cos^2x \ dx$$

Using the substitution $x=x+\frac{\pi}{2}$ we get

$$I=x+C-\displaystyle\int\cos^2(x+\frac{\pi}{2}) \ dx=x+C-\displaystyle\int\sin^2x \ dx$$

and thus $I=\frac{x}{2}+C$ which is obviously wrong.

So where's the mistake in the above argument??

Comment: I would say it's in your substitution usage. the $\sin^2$ term in the third line is being evaluated at a different 'version' of $x$ than from the first line, and so you cannot combine them.

Comment: Simpler version of the trick:  use the substitution $x\mapsto x+\pi$ to write $\int \sin x =-\int \sin x$ which tells you that $\int \sin x = C$.

Comment: $x\neq x+\frac {\pi}2$.  That's not how substitutions work.

Comment: Has your question been answered? If yes, you should accept an answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you put $u=x+ {\pi\over2}$,then you know that you will need to replace u with x.

Yet you used $x$, and forgot to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot say that $x=x+\pi/2$. This makes no sense mathematically.

It would be better to use
$$\sin^2 x = \frac{1-\cos(2x)}{2}$$

**Result:**
$$I=\frac{x}{2}-\frac{\sin(2x)}{4}+C$$

Comment: This does not address what is wrong with the argument.  It results in the correct answer.

Comment: @RossMillikan You are right. I will edit.

Answer (score 0):

Substitution does not work this way.

Even simpler functions can be used to illustrate the point:

Let $$J=\int x \,dx$$
 Then letting $x=x+1$ we see $$\int x\,dx =\int (x+1)\,dx=\int x\,dx + \int 1 \,dx\implies \int 1\,dx = C$$

But the fact is that $x\neq x+1$, so this sort of substitution was not valid.

True, in working with definite integrals, people are often careless and re-use the same variable name.  So long as you are careful to change the limits of integration along with the variable, there is no real harm in that (other than that it can be a bit confusing).